# Type Any has no subscript members

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, native

I'm finding it very difficult to pass my result in my completion callback to access in my ViewController. I can print my object when I do my for loop but I cant access specific values inside the object.

```
public func getMedia(completion: @escaping (Array<Any>) -> ()){
    Alamofire.request(URL(string: MEDIA_URL)!,
        method: .get)
        .responseJSON(completionHandler: {(response) -> Void in
            if let value = response.result.value{
                let json = JSON(value).arrayValue
                completion(json)
            }
        }
    )
}
```

In my ViewController

```
    getMedia(){success in
        for item in success{
            print(item["image"]) //This causes error
            print(item) //This prints the object perfectly
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is exactly what the error message is telling you: to subscript a variable, it needs to be declared as a type which supports subscripting, but you've declared your array as containing `Any`. And `Any`, being the most basic type there is, doesn't support subscripting.

Assuming your array contains dictionaries, declare your `getMedia` function like this instead:

`public func getMedia(completion: @escaping ([[String : Any]]) -> ())`

Or, if there's a chance that the dictionary might contain non-string keys:

`public func getMedia(completion: @escaping ([[AnyHashable : Any]]) -> ())`

If the values in the dictionary all have the same type, replace `Any` with that type as appropriate.